# Offline Form Submission - Data SYnc

Tags: json, forms, jsp, offline-browsing, app-offline.htm

We have a Loan Management System, and as everybody knows there is Field Investigation like Residence, Office, Business Verification.
So we have a requirement to actually support offline data entry also.
Meaning, the Field Investigation officer may download the "template" in his mobile or and the save data. Later when he is connected to App, he can sync that data.
As of now in our web application, we have JSP pages to render above specific forms.

1.) How to pragmatically download the template or html content.

2.) Save the form data in local DB or say browser db

3.) Then later sync that Json data with relational DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to download the jsp content from ajax request, then process it's html content and through HttpClient get the response for each and every url's (javascript, css) included in the package.

Zip it and then make it downloadable through browser.